# How to find out, if facebook ID is a user, group or page

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

i wonder if there's any way to determine, if a given ID is a user, group or page on facebook. I've checked the [FQL-Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/), but haven't found anything.

EDIT:

Nevermind. It seems, that ?metadata=1 does the trick (if the profile is accessible)

Answer (score 3):

As far as i'm aware, there is no way to simply get a "type" back from facebook, as they assume you know what the ID is supposed to relate too anyway.

The best thing i can think of is to find an attribute which is unique to each object, and check if it exists on the returned data from

`://graph.facebook.com/id`

You will want to check the documentation and return data for the best key/attribute to check, but from a quick look at the docs, you could possible check:

- If `company` exists, assume its an application id
- If `first_name` exists, assume its a user id
- If `owner` exists, assume its a group

The advantage being that once you determine the type of the ID, you already have the data you need for the object, to do whatever consequent actions.

N.B: The fact you don't know the type, leads me to believe that you don't have any `access_token` which will allow you additional permissions. Therefore you're restricted to public data, so be sure to use a key that does not require an `access_token` (i.e. i haven't tested this, but what gets returned from a group ID object, when a group is private? Owner may not be available and you may need to test for other keys, or allow for variations)

Comment: Thanks. I use the access token of my application. The result is different from a users access token, but it provides enough informations to fit my needs.

Comment: Okay, i guess i found a way. See the initial post.